# how to merge DLLs with each other

Tags: c#, dll, merge

I created a dll that Contain other dlls... I want to merge them. I mean when I want to use the new dll in another project, just import that. not the other contain ones.

for exp: I have a dll that its name is `NewDLL` and inside it there is another dll names: `UsedDLL`. 
now I want to give some one my `NewDll` and just it. I mean that the 2 DLLs dont be seprate. they merge in one.

I can merge my dll with application like [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528178/Load-DLL-From-Embedded-Resource?msg=4866923#xx4866923xx). but I want to merge dll's with each other

In additional I should say that I dont want to use ILMerge. I want to do that by code...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding assemblies inside another assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222655/embedding-assemblies-inside-another-assembly)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov ILMerge didnt work for me. its not for win 8

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this similar question: [Running ILMerge tool using .NET 4 on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220093/running-ilmerge-tool-using-net-4-on-windows-8) 
. The suggested solution is to use a tool named [GILMA](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17797/Gilma-GUI-for-the-ILMerge-Application-Revised-for) (GUI for ILMerge).

Or have a look at [ILMerge-GUI](http://ilmergegui.codeplex.com/) which claims to support .NET 4.5

Comment: Which one did you try? Gilma or ILMerge-GUI? And what was the error?